# TipTap/VueJS - How to detect a keypress

Tags: vue.js, tiptap, prose-mirror

I have a collaborative chat application that uses [tiptap](https://www.tiptap.dev/) for it's messaging area. I found it useful as it can support multiple formats already and can add some flexibility. However, I found myself stuck when looking for an event listener that listens for "enter" key. When the user hit the enter, I want to submit their chat and clear the editor.

I found this **onUpdate** event listener but I couldn't find exactly the place where it detects what key is pressed.

Sample code is below:

```js
mounted() {
  let editor = new Editor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: this.value
  });

  editor.on("update", e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.$emit("input", this.editor.getHTML());
  });

  this.editor = editor;
}
```

I'm using Vue2, btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the editor props, pass in a callback

```js
      handleDOMEvents: { 
        keydown: (view, event) => {
          if (event.key === "Enter") {
          }
          return false;
        }
      },
```

https://www.tiptap.dev/api/editor/#editor-props
https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#view.EditorProps

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I managed to do something similar. I use VueJS native keydown event to detect which key is pressed.

```js
<EditorContent class="editor" :editor="editor" @keydown.native="onKeydown" />
```

```js
methods: {
  onKeydown(e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && e.which == 13) {
      this.editor.commands.undo(); // i just "undo" the enter event to remove the space it made
      this.$emit("onEnter");
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.tiptap.dev/installation/vue2#5-use-v-model-optional

Comment: Works in Vue3 also, without the `native` tag though.

Answer (score 1):

```
  editorProps: {
    handleDOMEvents: {
      keypress: (view, event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          console.log('Heyyyy')
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

You can pass it as props to new Editor()